# awk to print incremental count of occurrences of unique values in each column

Tags: unix, awk

Would like print to incrementally count and then print the counts of the unique values in column 1 & column 2 & column 3 ...Column NF and Column $0
and if the word is appeared only one time of column 1, would like to print remarks as "No" as duplicated flag
and if the word is appeared more than one time of column 1, would like to print remarks as "Yes" as duplicated flag

Looking something like this

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; if (word == $1) { counter++ } else { counter = 1; word = $1 }; print $0 ",", "Yes/No", counter }'
```

For example, I am trying to check is there any duplicate information in the field $1 (Fruits Name) . 
Under Name field, "Apple" appears three times , "Orange" appears two times,"Mango" appear one time. 
So if any word is not repeated more than one time is consieder as "Name_Dup=No" duplicate and count of appears is "Name_Counter=1" (i.e Mango)

where "Apple" appears 3 times , so it is repeated/duplicated -remarks as "Yes" when it appears first time count is "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=1" , 
when it appears second time "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=2,  when it appears 3rd time "Name_Dup=Yes" and Name_Counter=3

Then need to check  each column $2, $3 .. till $NF and $0 ..

My actual input file is not sorted on any order. No of fields used to be vary like 10 fields, 12 fields and 15 fields etc

Input.csv

```
Name,Amount,Dept
Apple,10,eee
Orange,20,csc
Apple,30,mec
Mango,40,sss
Apple,10,eee
Orange,10,csc
```

Desired Output

```
Name,Amount,Dept,Name_Dup,Name_Counter,Amount_Dup,Amount_Counter,Dept_Dup,Dept_Counter,EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter
Apple,10,eee,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1
Orange,20,csc,Yes,1,No,1,Yes,1,No,1
Apple,30,mec,Yes,2,No,1,No,1,No,1
Mango,40,sss,No,1,No,1,No,1,No,1
Apple,10,eee,Yes,3,Yes,2,Yes,2,Yes,2
Orange,10,csc,Yes,2,Yes,3,Yes,2,No,1
```

For example , Please find below steps for reference.

**Step#1 - Field $1 check and Output**

```
Name,Name_Dup,Name_Counter
Apple,Yes,1
Orange,Yes,1
Apple,Yes,2
Mango,No,1
Apple,Yes,3
Orange,Yes,2
```

**Step#2 - Field $2 check and Output**

```
Amount,Amount_Dup,Amount_Counter
10,Yes,1
20,No,1
30,No,1
40,No,1
10,Yes,2
10,Yes,3
```

**Step#3 - Field $3 check and Output**

```
Dept,Dept_Dup,Dept_Counter
eee,Yes,1
csc,Yes,1
mec,No,1
sss,No,1
eee,Yes,2
csc,Yes,2
```

**Step#4-Field $0 check, combination of $1 & $2 & $3 and Output**

```
"Name,Amount,Dept",EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter
"Apple,10,eee",Yes,1
"Orange,20,csc",No,1
"Apple,30,mec",No,1
"Mango,40,sss",No,1
"Apple,10,eee",Yes,2
"Orange,10,csc",No,1
```

Comment: Not at all clear, could you please add more explanation about your expected output, as how come few fields are having NO also even their count is more than 1 in Input_file.

Comment: RavinderSingh13 , I have added Steps #1 to Step#4, please check and let know if you need any other details

Comment: Sorry to say but not clear still, can we have conditions when you need yes, when you need 1 etc etc please too here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

OP asks for, as I understand it, to show per line, per column, if a column value shows up more than once and give an occurrence count of this particular column so far.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==1{
   header=$0
   n=split("Dup,Counter",h)
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      for (j=1; j<=n; j++) header=header OFS $i"_"h[j]
   printf("%s,EntireLine_Dup,EntireLine_Counter\n", header)
   next
}
{
   r[++lines]=$0
   for (col=1; col<=NF; col++) v[col][$col]++
   v[col][$0]++
}
END {
   for (l=1; l<=lines; l++){
      n=split(r[l], s)
      res=""
      for (c=1; c<=n; c++)
         res=res OFS output(v,c,s[c])
      res=res OFS output(v,c,r[l])
      print r[l] res
   }
}
function output(arr, col, val){
    return sprintf("%s,%s", (arr[col][val] > 1? "Yes" : "No"), ++count[col][val])
}
```

with input:

```
$ cat input.txt
Name,Amount,Dept,Nonsense
Apple,10,eee,eee
Orange,20,csc,eee
Apple,30,mec,eee
Mango,40,sss,eee
Apple,10,eee,eee
Orange,10,csc,eee
```

this gives (I've deleted the header line manually, because I couldn't get it to fit in the code sample):

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
# deleted header line
Apple,10,eee,eee,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1,Yes,1
Orange,20,csc,eee,Yes,1,No,1,Yes,1,Yes,2,No,1
Apple,30,mec,eee,Yes,2,No,1,No,1,Yes,3,No,1
Mango,40,sss,eee,No,1,No,1,No,1,Yes,4,No,1
Apple,10,eee,eee,Yes,3,Yes,2,Yes,2,Yes,5,Yes,2
Orange,10,csc,eee,Yes,2,Yes,3,Yes,2,Yes,6,No,1
```

Comment: Marc Lambrichs, Wow, Excellent Code, Thanks a ton for good support  and up-voted !!!

Answer (score 0):

you are not providing what efforts you placed so far. Here is a hint where I would start. I guess since awk is the tool to use, start with shell command sort Input.csv and pipe it to awk. Populate an array when reading the input as well as an associative array with index the first field. 
I n the END section go over the array and see if you find the first field more than once. It takes a bit of time however that sounds like a homework. Not a production problem.

Comment: IMHO this will be more suitable for comments section rather than an answer.

Comment: Krassi Em, In real time scenarios, we are getting the quote from our supplier like country wise, region wise, product wise, product code wise , rate and cost information for A-Z destinations
 So , there is duplicate at country level, region level, product level etc , hence we will not be able to decide which duplicated rows need to be delete, post the above population of desired output , we can check and take some decision quickly.